# how to append nearest rows in a row in python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, append

I have a data table with 6 rows and 3 columns.

```
a b c 
d e f
g h i 
j k l
m n o 
p q r
```

I want to append nearest 2 rows in every row.  1 upper row and 1 under row will be appended.

```
a b c d e f g h i 
d e f g h i j k l
g h i j k l m n o
j k l m n o p q r
```

How can I do this? Thank you for your help. !!

Comment: This is a case for `as_strided`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by 1 lines of code. here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    ['j', 'k', 'l'],
    ['m', 'n', 'o'],
    ['p', 'q', 'r']
])
```

now shift the your DataFrame by 1 row and concat them

```
a_1 = a.shift(-1)
a_2 = a.shift(-2)
c = pd.concat([a, a_1, a_2], axis=1)
```

then correct rows in the new DataFrame

```
c = c.iloc[:-2]
```

full code as below

```
a = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    ['j', 'k', 'l'],
    ['m', 'n', 'o'],
    ['p', 'q', 'r']
])
b = pd.concat([a, a.shift(-1), a.shift(-2)], axis=1).iloc[:-2]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Don't forget to rename your index and columns.

Comment: this is working perfectly on python3.7 with pandas 0.25.3. please tell me your env

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strides](https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html) with flatten values by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), last select each `3th` row by indexing:

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

a = rolling_window(df.to_numpy().ravel(), 9)[::3]
print (a)
[['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i']
 ['d' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l']
 ['g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o']
 ['j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r']]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i
1  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l
2  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o
3  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r
```

General solution:

```
N = 3
M = len(df.columns)
a = rolling_window(df.to_numpy().ravel(), M*N)[::M]
```